# Java Swing Application Fullscreen mode

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, null-layout-manager

I'm working on a Swing Application. The application needs to be in fullscreen all the time including its components. I made the application fullscreen using `frmSwingapplication.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`
 
The JFrame contains 2 `JPanels`. One has `JTree` and upon the selection of node of the JTree, a new panel is painted in another JPanel.

The problem is, when the application is minimized, it looks like [image: this]

However when I maximize it, it looks like [image: this] That is, only covering the portion it did while minimized. How can I resolve this issue? I tried setting size and bounds of container I got from getContentPane() but it was all useless. I even tried it with `frame.pack();` and `frame.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use proper layout managers:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Certain layout managers will use all the available space and size/lay out components inside them to fill the whole area. Examples for such layout managers are `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout`.

Comment: Used BorderLayout with some changes made in the app.. It works fine now :) Thanks :)